# Data Trends in an Access Database

Tags: ms-access, trend

I am very new to using Access, and do not know many of the functions it is capable of, so my question may not be the clearest, but here goes...

I am trying to design a database to statistically monitor the values that are input. i.e. I have a Data Entry form, Control Charts, and the Tables are all full of Fields containing numbers.

One of the features I want is for it to be able to flag up trends in the data.
For example: If the last 5 values in a certain Field are trending upwards (last value is higher than previous, which is higher than previous, which is higher...etc) or downwards, then I would like a coloured textbox to appear (or something).

I have had a think, and I know how I would do it in Excel: I would reference specific values (cells) and have some code like:

```
If .Cells(iRow, 1).Value > .Cells(iRow - 1, 1) 
        And .Cells(iRow - 1, 1).Value > .Cells(iRow - 2, 1) etc etc Then
Sheets("Box1").Range("AA15").Interior.ColorIndex = 44
Trends = "3 consecutive points increasing"
```

I don't really know much about how Access works, but all I can seem to manage is to write a query that selects the latest 5 record entered... and then I'm stuck!

Is there a way of writing something in SQL that would do this? Could anyone give me some advice! Or point me in the right direction for some techniques that would make this possible?

Thanks.

The table of data I am working with has Fields listed: ID, Batch, Date, Field4, Field5, Field6.

All are numbers.

I would like to know if there are trends in the last 5 records for Fields 4, 5, 6 and 7.

Cross posted at:   http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=1421356#post1421356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to employ a running count. This is done using a nested [subquery](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php) where the source table is compared to itself (notice different aliases - `t1` and `t2`).

However, it really depends on how you want to consecutively order the fields. Below, I assume you want to find increasing field values for each ID by ordered Date. Alternatively, you can compare Batch by Date.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.[Date], t1.Field4,

  (SELECT Count(*) 
   FROM SrcTable As t2 
   WHERE t1.Field4 > t2.Field4 AND t1.[Date] > t2.[Date]
        AND t1.ID = t2.ID ) As RowCount

FROM SrcTable As t1
ORDER BY t1.[Date];
```

Save this query as a stored query or VBA recordset and then find the ID that has a RowCount of 5. This ID would have had 5 consecutively increasing field values. Also, above is only for Field4. Replicate for the other fields. And modify the SrcTable to actual table name.

Finally, while I do not know how your user interface looks like, you can conditionally format your textbox. You do so under form's Design View/Format tab (on ribbon) and selecting your textbox control. Set the Expression builder to the `DLookup` value of 5:

```
Expression Is:
    DLookUp("RowCount", "SavedQuery", "ID =" & Forms!yourformname!ID") >= 5
```

[DLookUp](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php) is an Access function among a family of functions: DSum, DAvg, DCount, DFirst, DLast. They allow quick field value searches in any of the database's stored tables and queries according to criteria. You can use them in SQL script, VBA code, and Expression builders.

One additional item: conditional format on a form does not update immediately when you edit existing or enter new data since the DLookUp is only calculated on the opening of form. In the AfterUpdate event of the textbook and AfterInsert event of form include the following VBA which factors in new data values:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acSaveRecord
Me!textboxname.Requery
```

[Requery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195253.aspx) is a method to recalculate the control source, row source, or record source of various objects.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Much appreciated. I will attempt this later tonight and let you know how I get on.

Comment: The first bit worked perfectly. But when conditionally formatting, the expression gives the error:

''The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.

You may have entered a comma without a preceding value or identifier."


Had a play with a few things but can't see what might be wrong?

Comment: Ok so it worked simply by removing the = at the beginning....

But now I've noticed the Row count does not seem to change even when I enter multiple data values that are increasing?

Comment: That may be due to conditional format not being updated. See my extension in answer. You need to requery the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who is reading and would find an answer to this useful...

I did the following to highlight any trends in the data I was collecting, as I could not get anything else to work:

Firstly I created textboxes containing the values I was interested in (the last 5 values in my table) by having the following code in the on load property of my form:

```
Me.Trend1 = DLookup("[Field]", "Table", "[ID]=Forms![Formname]![Subformname].Form.[ID]")
Me.Trend2 = DLookup("[Field]", "Table", "[ID]=Forms![Formname]![Subformname].Form.[ID]-1")
Me.Trend3 = DLookup("[Field]", "Table", "[ID]=Forms![Formname]![Subformname].Form.[ID]-2")
etc.
```

I then used the next bit of code to compare the values against each other and conditionally format my text box:

```
If Me.Trend1.Value > Me.Trend2.Value And Me.Trend2.Value > Me.Trend3.Value And Me.Trend3.Value > Me.Trend4.Value And Me.Trend4.Value > Me.Trend5.Value _
Or Me.Trend1.Value < Me.Trend2.Value And Me.Trend2.Value < Me.Trend3.Value And Me.Trend3.Value < Me.Trend4.Value And Me.Trend4.Value < Me.Trend5.Value _
Or Me.Trend1.Value > [Value] And Me.Trend2.Value > [Value] And Me.Trend3.Value > [Value] And Me.Trend4.Value > [Value] And Me.Trend5.Value > [Value] _
Or Me.Trend1.Value < [Value] And Me.Trend2.Value < [Value] And Me.Trend3.Value < [Value] And Me.Trend4.Value < [Value] And Me.Trend5.Value < [Value] Then


       Me.textbox.BackColor = vbRed
          Else: Me.textbox.BackColor = 5753088

End If
```